# regex for string combination and sequence rules angular 2

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, regular-language

Can someone help me with regular expression to use in **Validators.pattern()** ?

I want a regex for the following scenario : -

Researchers of a DNA-sequencing group need to store newly found sequences. Design a system that will accept a string, evaluate its validity. Valid pairs of DNA are represented by **PA,NY,OH,WV** and encapsulate other valid pairs. A sequence can be any number of pairs.

Example valid pairs:

- PNOWVHYA
- NY
- WOHV
- PPAA

*Exmaple invalid pairs:

- PAPA - not encapsulating
- NOH - no matching pair on N
- OONQHH - invalid character Q

Comment: And where is your code?

Comment: It isn't possible to check this kind of things with a regex pattern in javascript.

Comment: A better approach consists to split the string in the middle, then you reverse and translate the second part (P=>A, N=>Y, O=>H, W=>V), and then you test if the two parts are equals or not.

Comment: To implement this with regex would be a little crazy. But if you somehow could solve it with regex then do post the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would implement it in python. You can port the same logic to any other programming language.

```
from collections import Counter

code_to_test = 'OONQHH'
valid_codes=['PA','NY','OH','WV']
valid_code_letters=['P','A','N','Y','O','H','W','V']
w,x,y = False,False,False

#test condition 1
alpha=list(code_to_test)
if set(alpha) <= set(valid_code_letters):
    w=True

#test condition 2,3
if len(code_to_test)%2==0:
    if len(code_to_test)==2:
        if code_to_test in valid_codes:
            x=True
    else:
        a = [code_to_test[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(code_to_test), 2)]
        for q in a:
            if q in valid_codes:
                break
        else:
            x=True

#test condition 4
ccount = Counter(code_to_test)
if ccount['P']==ccount['A'] and ccount['N']==ccount['Y'] and ccount['O']==ccount['H'] and ccount['W']==ccount['V']:
    y=True

if w and x and y:
    print "VALID CODE"
else:
    print "INVALID CODE"
```

Output:

```
INVALID CODE
```

You have to check 4 conditions:

1. If letters of code to test is subset or equal set to given code
   letters.
2. If code is even letters.
3. If even letters then, is it encrypted.
4. If the encrypted code is constructed with valid codes.

Answer (score 0):

The category of strings you are describing is called a [Context Free Grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) and is known to be outside what a regular expression can be used to match for. However, if you limit the strings to a particular length, there are regular expressions that can be used for all strings matching that pattern within that length. For example:

All strings matching the pattern of length 2 or less:
`(PA|NY|OH|WV)`

All strings matching the pattern of length 4 or less:
`(P(PA|NY|OH|WV)A|N(PA|NY|OH|WV)Y|O(PA|NY|OH|WV)H|W(PA|NY|OH|WV)V)`

All strings matching the pattern of length 6 or less:
`(P(P(PA|NY|OH|WV)A|N(PA|NY|OH|WV)Y|O(PA|NY|OH|WV)H|W(PA|NY|OH|WV)V)A|N(P(PA|NY|OH|WV)A|N(PA|NY|OH|WV)Y|O(PA|NY|OH|WV)H|W(PA|NY|OH|WV)V)Y|O(P(PA|NY|OH|WV)A|N(PA|NY|OH|WV)Y|O(PA|NY|OH|WV)H|W(PA|NY|OH|WV)V)H|W(P(PA|NY|OH|WV)A|N(PA|NY|OH|WV)Y|O(PA|NY|OH|WV)H|W(PA|NY|OH|WV)V)V)`

As you can see, regular expressions are not designed to recognize patterns of this format. However, if you are using angular you can [use a custom validator](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html) instead. Consider this function which takes a string and returns true or false based on whether it matches the pattern:

```
function isValidDNASequence(input){
  for(i=0, j=input.length-1; i<j; i++, j--){
    if(!(
      (input[i]==='P' && input[j]==='A') ||
      (input[i]==='N' && input[j]==='Y') ||
      (input[i]==='O' && input[j]==='H') ||
      (input[i]==='W' && input[j]==='V')
    ) || i === j) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```